# how to show birthday reminder in label in ado.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I want to show birthday alert in my ado.net application in a label.

**How can I show that?**

I  want to show only name whose have birthday in particular date my fields, `name`, `id`, `DateOfBirth` and his datatype is `Datetim`e value store in that field in `mm/dd/yyyy` format .

please help me its very important to my project

I wrote one query but its not useful:

```
select PationName,ContactNo
from Physio_cureTable 
where DateOfBirth between getdate()-1 
                      and getdate()
```

iam wrote below code in my ado.net application but its give me blank data i check to entering today's date and month but then also show me blank data

```
 string result = "SELECT PationName FROM Physio_cureTable WHERE CAST(DateOfBirth AS DATETIME)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)";
            SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, con);

            con.Open();
            string actresult  =(string) showresult.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actresult))
                label18.Text ="Happy Birthday"+actresult+"!";
            else
                label18.Text = "There is No Birthday!!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare two date values and ignore their time value. 
For this, you can cast them to `DATE` and then compare them;

i.e. (MS SQL 2008)

```
SELECT PationName, ContactNo FROM Physio_cureTable 
WHERE CAST(DateOfBirth AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

GETDATE() returns today's date (with the time, so you need to cast it also).

i.e. (MS SQL 2005)

```
SELECT PationName, ContactNo FROM Physio_cureTable 
WHERE DateOfBirth >= DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE())
AND DateOfBirth < DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
```

Note that this compares the dates, where as if infact you want to compare the dates without the years, you would use a different approach:

```
SELECT PationName, ContactNo FROM Physio_cureTable
WHERE  datepart(d, DateOfBirth) = datepart(d, getdate()) AND
datepart(m, DateOfBirth) = datepart(m, getdate())
```

Comment: ericosg sir its give me 'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
error

Comment: ericogs sir i wrote this query 
 SELECT PationName, ContactNo FROM Physio_cureTable 
WHERE CAST(DateOfBirth as Date) =getdate()
but its give me Type Date is not a defined system type. error

Comment: ericogs sir i wrote this query
SELECT PationName, ContactNo FROM Physio_cureTable 
WHERE CAST(DateOfBirth AS DATE) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)

but still its give me Type Date is not a defined system type. error

Comment: what SQL server are you using?

Comment: ericosg sir its gave me still its give me Type Date is not a defined system type. error

Comment: sir im try your code but its give me blank data im enter date of birthday then also

Comment: thank you thank you very very much ericosg sir query working excellent thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assume that birthdate - '20100414 01:01:01', therefore the period for a condition '2013-04-14' - '2013-04-15' is necessary for you

For SQLServer2008+

```
SELECT PationName,ContactNo      
FROM Physio_cureTable
WHERE DateOfBirth >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, GETDATE(), DateOfBirth), CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
      AND DateOfBirth < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, GETDATE(), DateOfBirth), CAST(DATEADD(day , 1, GETDATE()) AS date))
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85ffa/2)

For SQLServer2005

```
SELECT PationName,ContactNo      
FROM Physio_cureTable
WHERE DateOfBirth >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, GETDATE(), DateOfBirth), CAST(datediff(d,0,GETDATE()) AS datetime))
      AND DateOfBirth < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, GETDATE(), DateOfBirth), DATEADD(day , 1, CAST(datediff(d,0,GETDATE()) AS datetime)))
```

Comment: alexander sir its give me 
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.
error

Comment: sir im try your code but its give me blank data im enter date of birthday then also

Comment: SQL 2008 supports DATE as a type, but SQL 2005 (op sql) does not.

Comment: @ericosg thanks for a clarification. In answer I added scripts for an of both versions.And +1 in your answer;)